# How do breakpoints work on modern high resolution devices?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, resolution

Modern phones and tablets have very high resolutions.

My Galaxy S7 Edge, for example, has a resolution of 1440 x 2560 pixels.

Common breakpoints for mobile devices seems to be around 768 pixels, such as in [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Example from [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

How is it that my phone displays the "responsive" version of websites even though it's resolution is arguably larger than most desktop monitors? From the example, it would seem my phone would always display the site in "desktop" mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the article [*A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel*](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)...

> I do know what web developers are interested in, however. They need
>   CSS pixels. That is, the “pixels” that are used in CSS declarations
>   such as `width: 300px` or `font-size: 14px`.
>
> These pixels have nothing to do with the actual pixel density of the
>   device. They’re essentially an abstract construct created specifically
>   for us web developers.
>
> It’s easiest to explain when we consider zooming. If the user zooms
>   in, an element with `width: 300px` takes up more and more of the
>   screen, and thus becomes wider and wider when measured in device
>   (physical) pixels. In CSS pixels, however, the width remains 300px,
>   and the zooming effect is created by expanding CSS pixels as much as
>   is needed.

See also:

- [A tale of two viewports — part one](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html)
- [A tale of two viewports — part two](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)

Comment: Thanks. But why do we still have to set things up to make the webpage responsive? When I say that this div width is 300px it should consider that 300px doesn't mean 300 actual pixels. And it should stay at the same size relatively in the cellphone. Right?