# Webpage pixel count bigger than screen resolution, why does that happen?

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I hope the title makes sense. Making an element with a set width and height, I found out that it's much smaller than I expected on mobile and also on Chrome's responsive view on the dev tools.

The reason seems to be that apparently even though a screen is supposed to be, let's say, 320px wide, the body of the webpage is over 900px wide and the width of my element gets reduced accordingly. On desktop devices that doesn't happen and it works alright.

This only happens in some webpages and I don't know the difference. What I'm making is an element that is supposed to be embedded by copy/pasting the code so I can't fix the code of the webpages, just the element itself.

What can I do and why could this be? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38665032/3597276

Comment: I don't really understand the question but did you add this meta-tag? : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: I bet that if you shared some of your css code, this could be solved in a trice.